# Pushforward under map of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

If $C$ and $D$ are smooth projective curves and $f:C\to D$ is a map, how do we compute $c_1(f_{*}\mathscr{O}_C)$?

I think applying Grothendieck Riemann-Roch from wikipedia yields the answer, but I'm hoping that is overkill, since I don't really understand GRR.

Comment: I am assuming that the map is non-constant (so that it is finite). Do you know the genus of $C,D$? If yes, then $c_1$ can be computed by if you know $\deg f$ and RR for vector bundles on a curve.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want, how does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is non-constant, it is finite and let $d=\deg f$. Then, $f_*\mathcal{O}_C=V$ is a rank $d$ vector bundle on $D$ and thus $\chi(V)=c_1(V)+d(1-g(D))$ by RR. On the other hand, $\chi(V)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)=1-g(C)$. So, $c_1(V)=(1-g(C))-d(1-g(D))$.

Comment: Note that the equality $\chi(V)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)$ in this very nice answer  results from the equality of the individual summands $H^i(D,V)=H^i(D,f_*\mathcal O_C)\cong H^i(C,O_C)$, which in turn results from $f$ being an affine morphism. See Hartshorne Exercise III,8.2, page 252.

Comment: Dear Mohan, I have taken the liberty to correct a typo in the  equation of the second line: I have replaced the incorrect $g(C)$ by the term $g(D)$, which you obviously meant.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for the kind correction.